# Android vs андроид

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю объединить метки [android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) и [андроид](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b4).

Comment: И ведь додумался кто-то по-русски её написать. И даже краткое описание добавить.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Синоним утверждён. Основная метка - [android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android).